# PHP Storm - FTP configuration

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to configure a project with remote server as a source (ftp). Everything I do is as they say to do it, When I test the connection its successful, but no files show up i the file tree. I have no idea what could be the problem.

I can access the ftp without a problem over browser, filezilla and everything else.

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you

Comment: when you say 'no files show up i the file tree', what file tree is meant? Please attach a screenshot of your configuration

Comment: @lena By file tree I mean FTP file tree. Never mind though, I have solved it by selecting Passive mode in FTP configuration. I posted the answer here, but someone deleted it...